# It doesn't recognize my property

Tags: c#

Category.cs

```
 using System.Collections.Generic;

 namespace DrinkAndGo1.Data.Models
 {
     public class Category
     {
         public int CategoryId { get; set; }
         public string CategoryName { get; set; }
         public string Description { get; set; }
         public List<Drink> Drinks { get; set; }
     }
 }
```

ICategoryRepository.cs

```
using DrinkAndGo1.Data.Models; 
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace DrinkAndGo1.Data.interfaces 
{
    public interface ICategoryRepository
    {
        IEnumerable<Category> Categories { get; }
    }
}
```

MockCategoryRepository.cs

```
using DrinkAndGo1.Data.interfaces; 
using DrinkAndGo1.Data.Models; 
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace DrinkAndGo1.Data.mocks 
{
    public class MockCategoryRepository : ICategoryRepository
    {
        public IEnumerable<Category> Categories
        {
            get
            {
                return new List<Category>
                {
                    new Category(CategoryName = "Alcoholic", Description = "All alcoholic drinks"),
                    new Category(CategoryName = "None-alcoholic", Description = "All None-alcoholic drinks")
                };
            }
        }
    } 
}
```

My issue is that Category and CategoryName and Description Marked as red.
MockCategoryRepository.cs Doesn't Recognize The PROP from the Category Class.
I know it can Recognize it without a constructor

Comment: Try formatting your code for readability

Comment: @Mafii I kind of like the effect of having the code block inside of the quote block. It looks fancy...

Comment: @Sudsy1002 look at the first revision it was terrible.

Comment: @Mafii Yes the code was not all together in the code block but I like the yellow border around it :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change these lines

```
new Category(CategoryName = "Alcoholic", Description = "All alcoholic drinks"),
new Category(CategoryName = "None-alcoholic", Description = "All None-alcoholic drinks")
```

To the following:

```
new Category{CategoryName = "Alcoholic", Description = "All alcoholic drinks"},
new Category{CategoryName = "None-alcoholic", Description = "All None-alcoholic drinks"}
```

You are trying to initialize the properties but have written it in incorrect style like calling constructor. [MSDN Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/how-to-initialize-objects-by-using-an-object-initializer)

Comment: The user who has voiced that the answer is not useful, please write the reason

Comment: Note that you don't need the `()` when you don't need to specify any arguments to the constructor, for an object initializer. I tend to omit them and consider that to be more idiomatic, although it's certainly just a personal opinion.

Comment: @DaisyShipton I agree with you but in this certain question I think it is better showing the reason of the error when there is present and the `()` and `{}`

Comment: But you're recommending the new code the OP writes in its place - I'm fine with explaining the cause of the error, but I'd generally suggest the cleanest code I could as the replacement.

Answer (score 0):

Samvel has shown a good solution using object initializers, but I'd like to suggest another option. If it's common to initialize a `Category` with a name and description, why not create a constructor accepting them?

```
public Category(string name, string description)
{
    // TODO: Consider renaming the property to just name, given that the type is Category
    CategoryName = name;
    Description = description;
}
```

Then you can have:

```
return new List<Category>
{
    new Category("Alcoholic", "All alcoholic drinks"),
    new Category("Non-alcoholic", "All Non-alcoholic drinks")
};
```

As an aside, C# 6 also allows you to write the property more succinctly:

```
public IEnumerable<Category> Categories => new List<Category>
{
    new Category("Alcoholic", "All alcoholic drinks"),
    new Category("Non-alcoholic", "All Non-alcoholic drinks")
};
```